# No overload for method ' ' takes 1 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i'm going to develop MVC application,In here it shows the error,But there's no any overload method here,Can anyone show me the error.

> > No overload for method 'GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers' takes 1 arguments

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(ICS.Models.UserModels.Customer_Supplier model1)
    {
        ICS.Business.ICSContoller.UsersController  _uc = new ICS.Business.ICSContoller.UsersController();
        Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        _uc.GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers(new ICS.Data.Customer_Supplier
        {
            FirstName = model1.FirstName,
            LastName = model1.LastName,
            DateOfBirth = model1.DateOfBirth,
            Email = model1.Email


        });

        return View(model1);
    }
```

Here is the method

```
 public IList<Customer_Supplier> GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers()
{
    return (from cs in context.Customer_Supplier
            where cs.IsActive == true
            select cs).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Show the method `GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Code Updated

Comment: `GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers()` is clearly defined to not be passed _any_ arguments, and yet you're creating a new instance of `ICS.Data.Customer_Supplier` and passing that to it.

Comment: Also, is `ICS.Business.ICSContoller.UsersController` an actual controller?

Comment: ohh... wrong method call here... Silly Mistake.thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _uc.GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers(new ICS.Data.Customer_Supplier
        {
            FirstName = model1.FirstName,
            LastName = model1.LastName,
            DateOfBirth = model1.DateOfBirth,
            Email = model1.Email


        });
```

above is the problem. you cannot pass anything in that method. If you do want to, you have to create a method, or anoverload that takes 1 argument

Answer (score 1):

You're method is `IList<Customer_Supplier> GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers()` while you try to call `void GetAllCustomersAndSuppliers(Customer_Supplier parameter)`.